# How to prevent duplicate mobile number in account using triggers?

Tags: trigger

How to prevent duplicate mobile no in account using triggers? that is Mobile number is already use in one account/customer creation,,now use same mobile number in another account/customer.I want to unique mobile no for the account/customer.so on that time how to prevent that duplicate mobile number? and how o display the error??

Comment: Why not use a custom field, and set it as unique?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the logic you can use to write the trigger.

1. Create before insert trigger on
2. Get all the existing records with that mobile no.
3. Loop over your trigger.new records and match the value
4. Add an error to the new records as needed

   ```
   trigger PreventMobile on Account(Before insert)
   {
     set<String> lstMobileno = new set<String>();
     for(Account acc : Trigger.new)
     {
         if(acc.mobilephone!=null)
            lstMobileno.add(acc.mobilephone);

    }

    //Query all existing records
    Map<String,Account> mapMobileNo = new Map<String,Account>();
    for(Account acc : [select id,mobilephone,Name from account where mobilephone in : lstMobileno])
    { 
     if(!mapMobileNo.containskey(acc.mobilephone))
         mapMobileNo.put(acc.mobilephone,acc);
    }

   //loop through the trigger.new
   for(Account acc : Trigger.new)
    {
       if(acc.mobilephone!=null && mapMobileNo.containskey(acc.mobilephone))
       {
         acc.addError('This Mobile no. is already used in ' + mapMobileNo.get(acc.mobilephone).Name);
       }
    }
   }
   ```

I have not covered all cases but this is the basic code which can work for you.

Answer (score 1):

If your org supports it, you might want to look into Duplicate Management.

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=managing_duplicates_overview.htm

This is a non-trigger solution (clicks not code!) so allows your System Administrators to take control of the process.

Comment: Hi Powlo, I use the Duplicate Management.I create the matching rule called as unique mobile no Account: CustomMobileEXACTMatchBlank = FALSE. Then i create duplicate rule Conditions (Current User: ProfileNOT EQUAL TOSystem Administrator). But is not working